# How many points to fill up Fate Meter?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

In *Kingdoms of Amalur*, you can fill up the fate meter by doing move combos, killing enemies, drinking potions, etc.

When you do a move combo/kill an enemy and it rewards fate points, you'll get a notice that tells you how many points you got (e.g., +24 fate points) in the top left of the screen.

If you open the menu to look at HP/Fate/MP, you can see your current/total HP and MP, but you can only see the percentage of fate you have (e.g., you might have 127/225 HP, 50% Fate, and 150/200 MP)

Out of curiosity, how many points does it take to fill up the fate meter to 100%, and does that value ever change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you get 50% of EXP as fate.

I did at level 18 at least, meaning you need 200 exp from creatures for 100% fate.

Comment: Sorry not EXP but fate points!

Comment: You can edit your post to fix any issues. I'm guessing you're saying that the "200 exp" should be "200 fate points". How did you come up with the 200 number?

Answer (score 0):

Based on personal experience, the formula of Fate being rewarded to the player-fighter, is based on a complex multi-dimensional consideration of many factors (surprisingly intelligent for a video game.) In terms of numeracy, one can say roughly the Fate meter exists as 0-265, or 300 to simplify; and the exact amount of "fate-energy" rewarded to the player, is reflexive of their creative prowess: using the same set of moves, the same finisher, etc. in "Reckoning" scenarios, results in diminishing returns, dynamically, of "fate-energy" and "XP".

The exact numerical value of fate-energy rewarded is moreover strongly based on the class of enemy defeated and the differential gulf, or lack thereof, in terms of "level", etc., between the player and the vanquished foe.

There is no unilinear, normed averaged number to answer such a question, so further mathematical motions when analyzing the game from certain particular angles, while, to some, might help understand matters, can mendaciously fail to convey reality to minds of different types.

The game is intelligently factoring in multiple planes of actuality in its calculus. When I say the Fate-meter can be translated as equally roughly 260 or so, the populist reductionist simplification, should not be mistaken for the actual, literal, underlying reality. What you and others have stated about a certain percentage as interfacing certain factors, is doubtlessly true in many cases; but not remotely absolutely, in the linearist sense minimally at the least... The game really was intelligently designed and developed.

What people are saying above, these are generalities and not monolithic absolutist brute facts, is all I want to express. These numeric, normed and linear-type generalities are not "untrue" but simply not sufficiently contextualized and, in light of the background of Amalur, the rare complexly woven alter-verse with an even more complexity-ridden programming, these rough exoteric trans-literations, lack a certain depth, given the game's intellectually-rigorous nature.

For example, or to be concrete: based on experience and "personal empiricist observation", if, say, your character just hammered into nothingness a grossly weaker foe ,3, 4 or so levels lower than your character, 0%...as in, pure nihility of nugatory nothingness...NO, none, not even one half one percent, no Fate-energy shall be given, period.

Multiple other coefficient criterial variables exist: The exact number of the player using the same identical attack modality, is the exact number the player is negatively mathematically evaluated, in a very sophisticated way...

And, on a different note, MORE IMPORTANTLY, generally, I have discovered, counter-intuitively, button-mashing here takes on an unexpected central role: when the silly random button letter comes up, no joking around, one must mash the button like wild. My wrist-watch estimated the length of Reckoning at exactly 3 seconds, or, if interpreted in different sense, 13 or 14 seconds; time is not on our side in button-mashing...the programming relies on the exact tapped number, the number of sensed taps of the button, in determining the resultant fate-sum and EXP, perhaps as the primary criterial dynamic, believe it or not...even more important than class-hierarchical differences, etc. When focused (i.e., caffeinated), approximately 20 presses of the indicated correct button multiplies the experiential reward by at least 100%...